# Sublime Text - Ignore files in search

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

There is a way to exclude a file (javascript compresed) from my searchs in sublime text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find > Find In Files... (`Ctrl+Shift+F` on Windows, `Cmd+Shift+F` on Mac)

Find: `string to find`

Where: `path/to/folder, path/to/another/folder, -*.min.js`

You can either manually type the comma-separated paths into the 'Where' input field or click the `...` button to the right of the field to select criteria. To exclude minified js files you would add `-*.min.js`

Comment: And can I set to exclude minified js files into my settings ?

Comment: "file_exclude_patterns": []

Comment: `"file_exclude_patterns"` will only exclude files from being displayed in the sidebar, not from searches

Comment: Will the find exclude patterns also exclude them from the quick file search/quick file opening system one can reach via `command P` on a mac?
(Just checked, its called: `Go To Anything...`

Because this command is pretty slow when I hit it, and I think it's because it has to search too many files.

Answer (score 6):

Yes!

`binary_file_patterns` will work.

```
 "binary_file_patterns": ["*.svg", "*.png", "*.otf", "*.pdf", "*.jpg", 
     "*.png", "package-lock.json", "node_modules/*"]
```